# Sql dacpacs exporting data

Tags: sql-server

From my understanding when extracting a sql database as a dacpac it includes the data structure with views/procs etc but no data.
a bacpac includes the structure and data but cannot be upgraded.

I read some where that dacpacs can include data now but I cannot find anywhere that shows how to do that. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible! Easy way to include data in DACPAC is to use `SQL Server Database project` in Visual Studio:

1. Add data to post-deployment script (`INSERT` command etc.).
2. Build the project - it gaves you a DACPAC file.
3. Go to SQL Server Management Studio.
4. Execute `Databases -> Deploy Data-tier application` command:

[image]

Now you have a new database with data from a single DACPAC file!